# PDF Modal display in expandable sections

Tags: javascript, jquery

- I have several expandable/collapsible sections on my webpage. The section is either expanded or collapsed when I click on the heading (h2). Each of these section also has a PDF link that I would like to be displayed in a modal when the link is clicked on. This works perfectly for the first section and corresponding PDF link. However, for the second section, when I click on the h2 heading, it expands the heading and displays the PDF modal. I only want the modal to be displayed when clicking on the link. Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // When a PDF link is clicked
    $('.pdf-link').click(function (event) {
        // Check if the click came from inside the expandable section
        if (!$(event.target).closest('.expandable-section').length) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // Show the modal
            $('#pdf-modal').show();
        }
    });

    // When the modal close button is clicked or when the background is clicked
    $('#pdf-modal .close, #pdf-modal').click(function () {
        // Hide the modal
        $('#pdf-modal').hide();
        // Stop the PDF from playing
        $('object, embed').each(function () {
            $(this).attr('data', $(this).attr('data'));
        });
    });

    // Below code allows expandable sections. Needs to be added here to avoid PDF displaying instead of expanding/collapsing section.
    $('h2').click(function (event) {
        // Check if the click came from inside the expandable section
        if ($(event.target).is('a.pdf-link') || $(event.target).closest('.pdf-link').length) {
            return;
        }
        // Hide the PDF modal
        $('#pdf-modal').hide();
        // Stop the PDF from playing
        $('object, embed').each(function () {
            $(this).attr('data', $(this).attr('data'));
        });
    });
});
```

Can anyone assist? I can provide my HTML but it is quite lengthy.

I tried to create an PDF modal display that is only activated when clicking on the link. However, it is expanding when I click on the heading which is only meant to expand or collapse the section that contains the link